# Adding a pattern to gitignore file doesn't catch subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore specific files that start with `cached`. In my `.gitignore` file I have the line `cached*` but when I do `git status` I get the following:

```
datasets/task1/thing1/cached_somethingsomething1
datasets/task2/thing2/cached_somethingsomething2
datasets/task3/thing3/cached_somethingsomething3
.
.
.
```

I've tried `**` as well, but it's the same result.

Is there a way to recursively ignore files, or do I have to specify ignore patterns for each subdirectory?

Comment: That doesn't look like output from `git status`: it doesn't start with `on branch ...` and none of the file names are prefixed with any of the staged / unstaged / untracked messages.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
**/cached*
```

Maybe you might prefer this:

```
datasets/task?/thing?/cached*
```

Or this:

```
datasets/task*/thing*/cached*
```

Comment: Another option is to add another .gitignore deeper in the path you want to block. I find this useful when different paths may have different owners/purposes.